# ActiveModel custom EachValidator not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

My EachValidator cannot work on Rails 4.1.5.

My `Product` model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tags

  validates :tags, tags_size: {minimum: 1, maximum: 10}
end
```

My Validator, I put it in app/validators/tags_size_validator.rb

```
class TagsSizeValidator < ActiveModel::Validator

  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if value.size < options[:maximum]
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must have at most #{options[:maximum]} tags.")
    end

    if value.size > options[:minimum]
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "must have at lease #{options[:minimum]} tags.")
    end
  end
end
```

end

I have made it autoload in application.rb

```
config.autoload_paths += %W["#{Rails.root}/app/validators/"]
```

When I put the validator at the same file as the Product model, it worked perfectly. But in separated file it failed. Are there any steps I have missed? Please advise. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try inheriting from `ActiveModel::EachValidator` rather than `ActiveModel::Validator`:

```
class TagsSizeValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
...
```

Also you shouldn't have to add it to your `autoload_paths` in Rails 4.1.

Comment: Thanks @Inkling, I have just tried EachValidator but unluckily, it's still not working. It looks like the model was loaded before the validators.

Comment: I don't know what could be the issue then. I have an `ActiveModel::EachValidator` set up in the same way you do (no `autoload_paths`) and it just works for me.

Comment: Have you tried stopping Spring and restarting the application? Checking that there's no added gems causing issues?

Comment: I stopped Spring and it's still not working. I found weird because I did it once before and it just worked well.

Comment: Ah! Sorry about it! My stupidity! The filename was just wrong. (tag_size_validator.rb and it should be tags_size_validator.rb). Thanks @Inkling.